# How to update google sheet with new outcome every time python script runs?

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, pygsheets

I have a python script with each time running ,it returns a new value. Then I need to add those values to a google sheet. So every day the outcome of the scripts will be added to a new row. I tried to use “pygsheet” lib but I can not handle the addition to new row for each day. How can I add the data to the last empty row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this using pygsheets. `insert_rows` can achieve this in a single line.

```
wks.insert_rows(wks.rows, values=[daily_value], inherit=True) # here wks is the worksheet object
```

If you dont want to add a new row or want to add value in a non-last row you can use `append_table`, assuming this is the only data in the sheet.  Here you have to make sure your sheet have enough rows to fit new value.

```
wks.append_table(values=[daily_value])
```

Comment: This works but adds the row to the last row not the last non empty row. So as there is 1000 rows by default the data is added to the 1001 row.

Answer (score 3):

First, get all values in the spreadsheet. You need to specify `include_tailing_empty_rows` and `include_tailing_empty` as `False`, so that empty rows will not be included in the count

```
new_row = ['firstname', 'lastname', 'Email', 'Number']
worksheet = gc.open('Sign Up').sheet1
cells = worksheet.get_all_values(include_tailing_empty_rows=False, include_tailing_empty=False, returnas='matrix')
last_row = len(cells)
worksheet = worksheet.insert_rows(last_row, number=1, values= new_row)
```

`insert_rows` adds the "new_row" list to the position immediately after "last_row".

You can check out other attributes of `worksheet` here https://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/worksheet.html

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet will add data to the last non-empty row.

```
#open the google spreadsheet 
sh = gc.open('name of the google sheet')

#select the first sheet 
wks = sh[0]

#retrieve all rows of the worksheet
cells = wks.get_all_values(include_tailing_empty_rows=False, include_tailing_empty=False, returnas='matrix')

#extract all non empty rows
nonEmptyRows = []
for i in cells:
    if i != []:
        nonEmptyRows.append(i)

#calculating the length 
countOfnonEmptyRows = len(nonEmptyRows)
type(countOfnonEmptyRows)

#defining the data
ls = ['G', 'H', 'I']


#inserting data 
wks.insert_rows(countOfnonEmptyRows, values=ls, inherit=True) # here wks is the worksheet object
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Connect with Google Sheet
# pip install pygsheets 
# append data on google sheet with existing data Final working
import pygsheets
import pandas as pd

#Change Path : excel file path
df=pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\Ankur\Desktop\Google Sheet\CET Not Open.xlsx")
#Change Path : Your Key File Path Json file for Google Sheet API
path=r'C:\Users\Ankur\Desktop\Google Sheet\our-brand-301715-306ddc60d5ce.json'
gc = pygsheets.authorize(service_account_file=path)
# Change Sheet Name : PythonDB to your googlesheet name
sh=gc.open("PythonDB")
wk1=sh[0]
cells = wk1.get_all_values(include_tailing_empty_rows=None, include_tailing_empty=False, returnas='matrix')
last_row = len(cells)
if last_row>1:
    wk1.set_dataframe(df,(last_row+1,1))
    wk1.delete_rows(last_row+1)
else:
    wk1.set_dataframe(df,(1,1))
print("Data inserted successfully....")
```